# Would it be possible to write this colon in an if / else statement?

Tags: java

From what I've been reading, the ":" in Java acts as an if / then / else statement. In my code, I would like to replace this operator with the actual code that it is supposed to represent, yet I'm coming up with a brain fart.

```
int array[] = new int[]{x,y,z};
int neg = 0;
for (int n : array) 
{
  if (n<0) {
    neg++;
  }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to read the array and list the number of negatives, but I'd like to try it without this operator or the for statement. I feel like its possible (as I am dealing with a finite amount of integers in the array) but I'm not entirely sure how to word int n into an if/else statement when it doesn't have an assignment. Kinda at a brain fart.

Comment: You're confusing the conditional operator (`?:`) with for-each loops.  See the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The [For-Each operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) `:` is distinct from the ternary operator ([JLS-15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)) `:`. You could do something like

```
// if (n<0) {
//   neg++;
// }
neg += (n < 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the below snippet of code you are saying for each int n in the array check if n is less than 0 if that is true add 1 to neg.

```
for (int n : array) 
{
  if (n<0) {
    neg++;
  }
}
```

You are still going to have to do the

```
for(int n : array)
```

But can do the check inside as so

```
neg += (n < 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

Which translates to, if n is less than 0 then add 1 to neg, if not add 0.

Here are some good examples. http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018